# Can I not divide a matrix by a float in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, typeerror

When I try to perform matrix operations for on an equation in Python, I receive the following error:

> TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

The way I translate this, is that Python is telling me that I cannot create a 1x1 matrix via matrix operations with float values, but that makes zero sense to me.

My code is here:

```
x0 = np.array([[-1.1], [1.1]])
dfx = lambda x: np.array([-400*x[0]*x[1]+400*np.power(x[0],3)+2*x[0]-2, 200*(x[1]-np.square(x[0]))], dtype='float32')

temp = np.zeros((2,1))
gamma = np.zeros((2,1))
delta = np.zeros((2,1))
hess = np.eye(2, dtype='float32') 

deltaX = np.dot(-hess,dfx(x0))
p = t*deltaX 
temp = x0+t*deltaX
q = dfx(temp)-dfx(x0)

htemp = hess + np.dot(1 + np.divide(np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(q,hess),q)), np.dot(np.transpose(p),q)), np.divide(np.dot(p,np.transpose(p)),np.dot(np.transpose(p),q)))
```

When testing the code, I am given an error when performing the division operation:

```
print(np.divide(np.dot(np.dot(np.transpose(q,hess),q)), np.dot(np.transpose(p),q)))
```

If anyone is curious about what equation it is, it is part of this guy:[image]

Comment: I agree, the `transpose` looks suspect.  It's not the division.  It's a function parameter that's the wrong type or size.  But also, what is the shape of `q`? Looks like it might be 1d.

Comment: You have some parenthesis mismatch there ;) instead of having a huge expression ,break down into smaller chunks and you'll spot it

Comment: Ah I love when I spend so long trying to figure out why my code is broken just for it to be something small like this (: Thank you for the help, I'll be breaking down that expression now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem appears to be `np.transpose(q,hess)` instead of `np.dot(np.transpose(q),hess)`, since the former is meaningless.

I also suggest breaking up the `htemp` terms into different variables (like T1 = hess, T2= 1+q^T H q/p^Tq , so on) and then sum them up, so the code will more trackable.